# Why is the issuer name field signed in X.509?

Tags: certificates, x.509

In the [X.509 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.1.2) it sais that the issuer name is to be signed.

Since we verify the certificate with the authenticated issuer's public key, it seems infeasible to forge the issuer name anyways. A different issuer name would lead us to choose a different entities public key which would never match the signature.

Could somebody please shed some light on this for me?

Comment: What would you gain by omitting it?

Comment: I do like these types of questions; they are useful for ferreting out bugs.  e.g. software shouldn't rely too heavily on the issuer name.

Comment: @CodesInChaos It is not so much what you would gain by going back, but rather why it was designed that way in the first place. I am learning about IT Security at the moment an was thaught to be very precise about the goals I want to achieve with crypto in a protocol. Since I could not find a reason behind including the issuer name in the part which is signed in X.509, I thought, well, maybe I missed sth. and sb. else knows..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Everything* in a certificate is signed. It is much simpler to sign the whole lot than to sign only parts of it; skipping the issuer name would not gain much anyway (the hashing part of the signature is really fast).

We can imagine a sort-of-X.509 with the issuer name being excluded from the signature; it does not seem, *at first glance*, to be terribly weaker, but this would deserve a lot of serious investigation to be sure of it. Since there is very little gain in excluding the issuer name from the signature, the exercise would be rather pointless.